# Is there Any Way to Enforce RuntimeUnenhancedClasses in EE Configuration

Tags: openjpa, openejb

I just spent a half hour debugging some new code that's not broken because I forgot to check (again!) my logs for this dreaded message:

```
 WARN   openjpa.Enhance - Creating subclass for ...
```

I'm running OpenJPA 2.1.0 inside an OpenEJB 3.2 snapshot build, Java 1.6.0_25, and Eclipse Helios.  My entities are enhanced using the ant PCEnhancerTask.

My META-INF/openjpa.xml contains

```
 <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />
 <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="false" />
```

Is there anyway with this EE configuration to have OpenJPA enforce the RuntimeUnenhancedClasses option as it does in an SE configuration?

I *suspect* my 'real' problem stems from an Eclipse svn update that sometimes touches my JPA entity source, causing a build that overwrites my enhanced classes.

It's frustrating how often I run a unit test from the IDE that fails in some weird way, and I go digging through my code looking for a problem when all I need to do is run the enhancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `<property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />` META-INF/persistence.xml.

Looks like we're logging this action on debug level (maybe it should be info level), but OpenEJB will set that property to the default as it was in OpenJPA 1.x so that apps that worked with OpenEJB 3.1.x/OpenJPA 1.x will still work without modification in 3.2.x.  If the property is already set in the persistence.xml it will never be overridden, so setting it there will have the effect you want.

Open to suggestions on how to save others in the same boat some time in the future.  Seems either looking in the openjpa.xml file and seeing the property set already or issuing the log message on info would do it  -- or both.

Comment: This works, with a helpful OpenJPA log error.  Not sure why it didn't last week using suggestion from @Rick ...

Comment: As for logging the action, OpenJPA already logs WARN, it's just my (many?) logs during testing are over used which is why I miss it.  I've optimized my workaround to verify each JPA entity implements PersistenceCapable, so the problem is behind me, but to assist people migrating from JPA to EJB/JPA, I'd suggest honoring openjpa.xml entries.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like for whatever reason your properties aren't being picked up when running in the container.

I have a number of possible solutions:

1. Try setting your properties in META-INF/persistence.xml. I assume you have these properties in the openjpa.xml file for a reason, but it might help us figure out where the real problem is.
2. Set -Dopenjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses=false as a JVM property. This will apply to all PUs for a given JVM.
3. Move to a version of OpenJPA that is >= 2.0.0. RuntimeUnenhancedClasses was turned off as the default behavior in that release.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Other properties are definitely picked up from openjpa.xml, but I followed your advice and setting on jvm and in persistence.xml still produce subclassed entities.  I think class transformation is a requirement of the JPA spec(9.5/9.5.1), IMHO no provider I've used does it 'right' (for me).  The solution I've implemented is to construct each entity prior to bootstrapping the container and ensure they're instances of org.apache.openjpa.enhance.PersistenceCapable